# Index out of range custom cell TableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to populate 3 custom cells into a `TableViewController`.
but I always get index out of range error. I`m not sure whats wrong with my code. anyone can help me, I'm newbie in swift.

but when i use 0 for `numberOfRowsInSection` return, the output is the first cell.

here's my code :

```
class testResize: UITableViewController {

    @objc var comments = [AnyObject]()
    @objc var images = [UIImage]()
    var getImg = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadPosts()

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let getCom = comments[indexPath.row]
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: testResizeHeadCell.self), for: indexPath) as! testResizeHeadCell
            let user = getCom["nickname"] as! String
            let ava = getCom["ava"] as! String

            if ava != "" {
                let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: ava)!, cacheKey: ava)
                cell.avaImg.kf.setImage(with: resource)
            }

            cell.username.text = user

            return cell
        }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: testResizeCell.self), for: indexPath) as! testResizeCell

            cell.setCustomImage(image: images[indexPath.row])

            return cell
        }else {
            let getCom = comments[indexPath.row]
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: testRezieTextCell.self), for: indexPath) as! testRezieTextCell
            let text = getCom["text"] as! String

            cell.explaination.text = text

            return cell
        }
    }
```

here is my load function :

```
@objc func loadPosts() {
        let uuid = "959D1073"
        let url = URL(string: "some/url.php")!
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let body = "uuid=\(uuid)"
        //print(body)
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute:  {
                if error == nil {
                    do{
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                        self.comments.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                        self.images.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                        guard let parseJSON = json else {
                            print("Error While Parsing")
                            return
                        }

                        guard let posts = parseJSON["posts"] as? [AnyObject] else {
                            print("Error while parseJSONing")
                            return
                        }

                        self.comments = posts.reversed()
                        print(self.comments)
                        for i in 0 ..< self.comments.count {
                            let path = self.comments[i]["path"] as? String
                            self.getImg = [path!]
                            if !path!.isEmpty {
                                let url = NSURL(string: path!)!
                                let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
                                let image = UIImage(data: imageData! as Data)!
                                self.images.append(image)
                            } else {
                                let image = UIImage()
                                self.images.append(image)
                            }
                        }
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        //print(posts)
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }else{
                    print(error!)
                }
            })
        }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: You are returning 3 in `numberOfRowsInSection ` method. If you receive less than 3 comments from the api, it will crash

Comment: You should not use DispatchQueue.main.async for your dataTask. You should only use main thread for UI updates. I do not know your implementation but, your numberOfRows method also needs some if else statement as your cellForRowAt method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have a single comment and 3 cell type and when you use indexPath.row happen some thing like this :

for example :
comments = {[{nickname : "mahdi" , ava : "url"} ]}

```
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let getCom = comments[0]
        let user = getCom["nickname"] as! String
        let ava = getCom["ava"] as! String
    }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
      images[1]
    }else {
        let getCom = comments[2]
        let text = getCom["text"] as! String
    }
```

but you have just one comment and when you call comments[1] or commens [2] ,  you get index out of range error

please try this code :

```swift
class testResize:UITableViewController {

    @objc var comments = [AnyObject]()
    @objc var images = [UIImage]()
    var getImg = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadPosts()

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return (self.comments.count == 0 ? 0 : self.comments.count + 2)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let getCom = comments[indexPath.row]
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: testResizeHeadCell.self), for: indexPath) as! testResizeHeadCell
            let user = getCom["nickname"] as! String
            let ava = getCom["ava"] as! String

            if ava != "" {
                let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: ava)!, cacheKey: ava)
                cell.avaImg.kf.setImage(with: resource)
            }

            cell.username.text = user

            return cell
        }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: testResizeCell.self), for: indexPath) as! testResizeCell

            cell.setCustomImage(image: images[indexPath.row - 1])

            return cell
        }else {
            let getCom = comments[indexPath.row - 2]
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: testRezieTextCell.self), for: indexPath) as! testRezieTextCell
            let text = getCom["text"] as! String

            cell.explaination.text = text

            return cell
        }
    }
```

and change your numberOfRowInSection :

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return (self.comments.count == 0 ? 0 : self.comments.count + 2)
}
```

Comment: still no luck :(

Comment: @ビートフリークス Do you want to return 3 cells even if you have only one comment?

Comment: OMG, that`s what I want :) 
thanks so much your code actually work. you save my day T_T
ほんとうにありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you load your posts asynchronously.
But you do not check if there are actually enough elements in the array. You should check if there are actually enough elements in the array before you access it with a fixed index.

Additionally, you should change your numberOfRows method to the following:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return self.comments.count
}
```

After you have loaded your posts, you can then call

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: I already try with self.comments.count as return numberofrow but still only first cell show T_T

Comment: Then only one comment was loaded. Can you maybe add the loadPosts func?

Comment: What is the output of the line "print(self.comments)"?

Comment: this the output :
[{
    ava = "";
    email = "asdasd@asdasd.com";
    id = 19;
    nickname = "\U30d0\U30fc\U30d0\U82b1\U7530";
    path = "post-959D1073-14EC-419A-B2D8-B4E9E45A073D.jpg";
    pcategory = mens;
    pdate = "2019-05-08 12:55:37";
    phomepost = on;
    text = "\U8d64";
    username = asdasd;
}]

Comment: @ビートフリークス Till you receive a response from the api your self.comments.count is 0. But you are returning 3 in numberOfRowsInSection method. Return self.comments.count in numberOfRowsInSection method